# how to navigate from ionic sideMenu to page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, apache-cordova

i have just recently implemented the ionic side menu plus tabs in my app but when i click on the item in the sidemenu, it doesn't take me to that page. i have looked at lots of examples but they only got me more confused.
here's my side menu code

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
      if (cordova.platformId === 'ios' && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive  
      
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'TabsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })

      //i'm trying to setup an abstract state for the sideMenu directive here
    .state('app', {
          url: '/app',
          abstract: true,
          controller: 'TabsCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
      })


  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.play', {
    url: '/play',
    views: {
      'tab-play': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-play.html',
        controller: 'PlaysCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
.state('tab.play-detail', {
    url: '/play/:playId',
    views: {
        'tab-play': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/play-detail.html',
            controller: 'PlayDetailCtrl'
        }
    }
})

  .state('tab.live', {
      url: '/live',
      views: {
        'tab-live': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-live.html',
          controller: 'DashCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    
  .state('tab.win', {
    url: '/win',
    views: {
      'tab-win': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-win.html',
        controller: 'WinCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.win-detail', {
      url: '/win/:playId',
      views: {
          'tab-win': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/win-detail.html',
              controller: 'winDetailCtrl'
          }
      }
  })
  .state('app.aboutUs', {
      url: "/aboutUs",
      views: {
          'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: "templates/aboutUs.html",
              controller: 'AboutCtrl'
          }
      }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/play');

});

.controller('TabsCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    $scope.openMenu = function () {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
    }

})

.controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    
})
```

```html
<ion-side-menus>

    <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon"><span class="icon ion-ios-close-empty"></span></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>

    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-light"></ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content has-header="true">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item href="#/app/aboutUs" menu-close><i class="icon ion-information margin-right"></i>About</ion-item>
                
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

i just simply hvn't been able to figure out how to get it to work.

Every assistance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you try changing 'href="#/app/aboutUs' with' ui-sref="app.aboutUs"' ?

Comment: i did and after changing the sideMenu abstract state templateurl to the about page, it redirected. but it isn't creating that page on the stack. it is supposed to have some form of navigation history